# Does my Postgresl column contain only digits?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to check if a `character varying` type column contains only digits or null values with **Postgresql**?

Maybe something like (this syntax is incorrect):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN mycol ~ '^[0-9\.]+$' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
LIMIT 1
```

I'm expecting `TRUE` or `FALSE` as final result for the whole column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to to know if the values in all rows are digits, you can use

```
select not exists (select *
                   from mytable
                   where not (mycol ~ '^[0-9\.]+$'))
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=22b9bf3ff6966a4ce7e17a2c5f513e8d)

Comment: Instead of a list of rows, I need the answer: `true` if `mycol` contains only digits, and `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

To get Nulls use COALESCE(mycol, 1) -- will return 1 if the value in mycol is NULL.

For checking numerics you could use regex LIKE'^[0-9]*' it wont detect decimal dots (dont know if your data have decimals)

BR!

Comment: It doesn't have decimal dots, just digits like `123` or nothing (null).

Comment: Then that regex should work (starting with an undefined number (*) of digits from 0 to 9 ([0-9])

Comment: How can I get a result `true` or `false` for the whole column ?

Comment: `LIKE` does not support regular expressions, `~` is the correct operator